# How to translate "inclusive" and "exclusive"?

Tags: translation

In my iOS app, users can select a start date and an end date to search for stuff posted in that range

I added a little footnote thingy that says:

> The start date and end date are both inclusive

I just want to tell the user that stuff posted at the start date and the end date will be in the results of the search.

If you don't understand, here's another example,

> My age is between 1(inclusive) and 100(exclusive)

This means that my age can be 1 but it can't be 100.

How can I translate "inclusive" and "exclusive" into Chinese?

I tried

> 开始日期和结束日期会被包含在搜索结果中

But it sounds kind of long. Is there a more concise translation? Also, how can I translate the second example?

> 我的年龄是介于1（包括）到100（不包括）之间

That just sounds weird.

Comment: 包括（在内），不包括（在内），alternative suggestions:公布（posted)于开始日期与结束日期的材料(stuff)会（被）包含在搜索结果中，我的年龄在（包括）１到（不包括）100之间 （到 can be replaced by 至）

Comment: in preceding comment replace 公布（posted)于开始日期与结束日期 by 于开始日期与结束日期公布（posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Chinese people just don't use the straight forward translation of these two words to express this kind of situation.

The start date and end date are both inclusive. 
起止日期均包含在内。

- You didn't mention anything about "search result" in your English version so why bother that in Chinese?

My age is between 1 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive). 
我的年龄在 1（含）至 100（不含）之间。

- Excuse me? Why don't you just say your age is between 1 and 99 inclusive? Your age is a float?
- By the way, just in case you are going to release your app - your punctuation in English was wrong, there should be a space added before each left bracket. Better review these things carefully before your publish an iOS app, in order not to lower the overall user experience.